# Extracting NDVI for the certain location

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am new to Google Earth Engine and QGIS. I have a Polygon of a city and I have a CSV file for 30000 unique geocode (belonging to the participants who were entered in the study)
I want to obtain the value of the NDVI at each location at the start time of the study (which is 2014) and then I want to have the mean NDVI for the period 2014-2016 at each location. I mean I should have two values for the NDVI.

here is the code but I don't know how to change it to have min, max, and mean NDVI in 30000 geocode. I mean is it possible to have "min, max, and mean NDVI" just in the desired location?

````
Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'geodesic polygon');

var imagecol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
  .filterDate('2014-05-01', '2016-07-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(5, 7, 'month'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false)

var getNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = imagecol.map(getNDVI);

var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');
var NDVI = greenest.select('NDVI');

var NDVI = NDVI.clipToCollection(geometry);

var zonalNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegions({
  collection: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:3310',
});

print(zonalNDVI);
Export.table.toDrive({collection: zonalNDVI, fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'}); ```
````

Comment: Why is there a QGIS-tag on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your geometry looks like you can map over each feature and select the ndvi of the entire period and your first image with these two functions:

```
  var ndviFirstImage = withNDVI.first().select('NDVI').reduceRegion({
    geometry: point.geometry(),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:3310'
  }).get('NDVI')
  // print(ndviFirstImage, 'ndviFirstImage')
  
  var ndviTotal = NDVI.reduceRegion({
    geometry: point.geometry(),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:3310'
  }).get('NDVI')
```

See the link for the full mapped function:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b59b1eda0c521322fea31c7ee1375f1d

EDIT
Forgot to change the export function:

```
Export.table.toDrive({collection: mappedFunction.flatten(), fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d4e679acf04ff44d99f38577d96cf947

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the file to export, I edited the answer. Does it work now? Can't ofcourse tell if it works for your csv because I don't have it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I apologize if my question is stupid. As I am a public health researcher and it is a little difficult for me to understand the coding context. I added the CSV file as an asset but when I click on it to see the asset detail I see this "The table may not have valid geometries." the file has 3 columns including PID, X, and, Y (PID 1078  X 37°57'33.0 Y 55°31'02.0)  @Jobbo90

Comment: Upon uploading you need to specify which columns contain the x,y coordinates and make sure the format of your values are understandable. Often degree symbols are not a readable format.